# How should I implement video transitions with Metal Kit and AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, video-processing, metalkit

I am making a video editor and so far I have been able to apply filters to a single frame. The way I currently have everything set up works perfectly. It's a lot of code to show and I don't really need help with the code specifically, so I'll just explain what I do. I use a video composition, WITHOUT a custom compositor that has one `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`, but multiple `AVCompositionTracks` (one for each asset) in my `AVMutableComposition`. Each track has its own layer instructions that handle scale, orientation, and position for each video. I then extract frames using a player item video output and render the frames with metal to apply filters and effects. This works really well and the performance is great.

Now I am faced with applying transitions, which requires me to overlap tracks in the `AVMutableComposition`. The problem with this is that the video output can't extract frames from specific trackID's and will only extract the top layer. Also, when I overlap tracks, the video doesn't show at all. So I came to the conclusion that I need a custom compositor. I implemented the compositor, but there are a few problems. I can't use layer instructions, but I know this can easily be solved by handling my transforms directly through my vertex shader. The biggest issue is that I need filters to be applied to each frame before the transition is done. For example, a transition between A and B: when I extract frames from track A for the transition, I need all of track A's filters and effects to be applied. When I extract frames from track B I need all of track B's filters to be applied. Then I need to render the transition with the filtered frames from A and B. I can do this in the compositor, but I won't be able to make live updates. I need live updates for my app, for example, changing the intensity of track A's filter with a slider should show every single increment updated live on the player. This solution doesn't allow for that since I would have to change the entire video composition to change the properties of the instructions and/or video compositor.
I've also looked into using an `AVAssetReader`, however, I am not sure if this will be fast enough or be able to handle seeking through videos efficiently.
So to recap, what I need is a way to extract frames from specific tracks that are overlapped and allow for live updates of any filters. If anyone can lead me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. Thank you.